# Ayuda para validar formulario antes de enviar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente funcion que me valida si existe el email ingresado en la base de datos y me funciona bien

```
var emailExistente = false;

//validar email en el registro
$("#correo_usuario").change(function(){

  var email = $("#correo_usuario").val();

  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append("validarEmail", email);

  $.ajax({
    url:"views/modulos/ajax.php",
    method:"POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(respuesta){

      if(respuesta == 0){

        $("label[for='correo_usuario'] span").html('<p class="text-danger">Este email ya existe en la base de datos</p>');
        $("input[id='correo_usuario']").parent().addClass('has-danger');

        emailExistente = false;
      }

      if(respuesta == 1){

        $("label[for='correo_usuario']").parent().addClass('has-success');
        $("label[for='correo_usuario'] span").html('');
        $("input[id='correo_usuario']").parent().removeClass('has-danger');
        $("input[id='correo_usuario']").parent().addClass('has-success');

        emailExistente = true;
      }

    }

  });

});
```

Ahora el problema es que a pesar de que el correo existe y le coloque un false igual me esta ejecutando el submit, les agradeceria si podrian ayudarme a crear una funcion o algo que me impida enviar el submit si el email existe

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar en tu pregunta el código donde validas `submit` y/o el `HTML`?

Comment: estoy intentando usar esta validacion, pero no me funciona igual me hace el submit
`function validarRegistroU() {

    //valido el nombre 
    if (emailExistente = false){
      alert("El correo ingresado ya esta en uso")
      return false;
    }
  }`

Comment: @jorgnv Tendrías que hacer la comprobación con doble `==` ya que si no siempre le estás asignando el valor `false` y por lo tanto siempre te entra en la condición.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, en los comentarios te preguntan que dónde validas el formulario y colocaste:

```
function validarRegistroU() { 
  //valido el nombre
  if (emailExistente = false) {
    alert("El correo ingresado ya esta en uso") return false;
  }
}
```

Pero el IF tiene sólo un signo de igual (=) en lugar de dos (==) aunque es redundante.

Si emailExistente = true, entonces puedes usar:

```
if(emailExistente) // Si es true, entonces haz ...
```

Revisa ese IF.